# How do I fetch the latest FFmpeg binary archive for Windows when there seems to be no obvious way to automate this?

Tags: windows, ffmpeg, automation

This is the official download page for FFmpeg: http://ffmpeg.org/download.html

For Windows, it links to: https://ffmpeg.zeranoe.com/builds/

I have carefully studied both of those pages now and I cannot see any way in which I could automate the following tasks:

1. Determine which is the current stable version of FFmepg.
2. Determine the URL to the Windows archive for this current stable version.

If I locally type:

```
ffmpeg.exe -version
```

It outputs this:

```
ffmpeg version N-94664-g0821bc4eee Copyright (c) 2000-2019 the FFmpeg developers
built with gcc 9.1.1 (GCC) 20190807
```

It seems like "N-94664-g0821bc4eee" is my current version. Ahem. I frankly don't understand why they can't use a simple "1.2.3" scheme, but I guess I will just check if my current version is *different* from whatever has been determined to be the latest stable version, rather than trying to "compare" them as integers or sane version strings.

I've just gone through the same thing with ExifTool, but at least they had a simple URL to display the current latest version, and had a predictable URL scheme for the Windows ZIP file containing the binaries. This is not the case with FFmpeg, which is really strange to me.

(Please don't tell me to use Chocolately.)

Comment: Well https://ffmpeg.org/download.html#releases says the latest stable build is `4.3`. Putting `4.3` into the version box of https://ffmpeg.zeranoe.com/builds/ shows at the bottom of the page `ffmpeg-4.3-win64-static.zip` next to the download button. Not easy to automate but the information is there.

Answer (score 1):

---

*Note that in the answer below, I am focusing on the FFmpeg builds provided by Zeranoe. This information was up-to-date as of July 2020. Please forgive me if I miss anything or cover something you already know. =)*

---

**TL;DR**

Zeranoe has "latest" build `.zip` files for its most recent Git builds, licensed under the GPL 3.0 (I believe these are updated every few days). If you are happy with statically-linked versions, you can get them from:

- https://ffmpeg.zeranoe.com/builds/win32/static/ffmpeg-latest-win32-static.zip
- https://ffmpeg.zeranoe.com/builds/win64/static/ffmpeg-latest-win64-static.zip

Note that statically-linked builds aren't the only available builds. Particularly, you can also substitute `shared` (for shared libraries) or `dev` (for dev versions) in place of `static` in the URLs above to access those Git builds as well.

Unfortunately, for regular non-Git release versions (what I assume you mean by "current stable version"), there doesn't seem to be an equivalent automatically updated file that I could find. So you are likely stuck examining HTML for recent versions.

---

**Overview**

> I cannot see any way in which I could automate the following tasks [...]

*Determining The Current Stable Version*

Assuming you do not wish to use the "latest" Git version `.zip` files detailed above, the basic process (currently) would likely be to use a script (or scripts) to:

- Download a given HTML page from Zeranoe.
- Extract just the `<a>` elements from that page.
- Use the text in those `<a>` elements to determine the non-Git release version of FFmpeg you wish to download.
- Feed a script-determined URL containing that version information to some download tool (possibly the script itself).

For further details regarding the first step, see the *Page Source Options* section towards the end of this answer. I have also included an extremely minimal PowerShell example after that section which may help with `<a>` text element extraction. Be aware that none of the `<a>` elements in the relevant HTML page sources appear to hold full download URLs at this time.

Zeranoe appears to order its release listings for both regular and Git releases automatically, so if you don't care to analyze `<a>` elements or filenames individually, you may be able to cheat by simply using a set position to determine the latest non-Git version.

---

*That is, the latest non-Git FFmpeg version/filename is currently contained in either the first `<a>` element in the page source (for the rendered version of `https://ffmpeg.zeranoe.com/builds/`) or the second-to-last/third-to-last `<a>` element in the page source (for server-generated directory listings).*

---

*Determining A Windows Archive URL*

I do not believe there is a good way to *automatically* determine the URL to the Windows archive for a given release. You'll likely need to simply rely on observations about how the site is currently constructed (meaning you will probably need to tell your download script how to construct URLs).

**Version Names**

Speaking solely of the current [FFmpeg builds from Zeranoe](https://ffmpeg.zeranoe.com/builds/), determining the latest versions of FFmpeg from `<a>` element text shouldn't be too difficult.

- For regular releases, a simple "1.2.3" scheme (as your refer to it) is used. So ex. version `4.3` is more recent than version `4.2.3`.
- For up-to-date Git builds (which are released between "major" versions, above), the current scheme is to mark them by the date they were built (`year/month/day-gitstuff`).

Assuming that a Git build was marked `20200628-4cfcfb3`, the portion after the dash (ex. `-4cfcfb3`) could be dropped, leaving `20200628` and the conclusion that this version of FFmpeg was built on  06-28-2020 (or perhaps 28-06-2020, depending on where you live).

> If I type `ffmpeg.exe -version`, it outputs [...]

The current versions of FFmpeg for Windows from Zeranoe use the same naming schemes in their `-version` banners as for the version names listed on the website:

*ex. Zeranoe FFmpeg Banners*

```
ffmpeg version 4.3 Copyright (c) 2000-2020 ...

ffmpeg version git-2020-06-28-4cfcfb3 Copyright (c) 2000-2020 ...
```

**Download URL Format**

> I've just gone through the same thing with ExifTool, but at least they had a simple URL to display the current latest version, and had a predictable URL scheme for the Windows ZIP file containing the binaries. This is not the case with FFmpeg, which is really strange to me.

While it may not be immediately obvious, all the JavaScript on `https://ffmpeg.zeranoe.com/builds/` does is "reconstruct" the URL linked to the primary "Download Build" button (near the bottom of the page) on the fly, linking it to different static download options.

Poking around with a few different options, the construction of the final download URL is fairly straightforward:

*ex. Zeranoe FFmpeg Download URL Construction*

```
url/platform/linking/ffmpeg-version-platform-linking(.zip)(-lgpl.zip)
```

Where:

- `url` is `https://ffmpeg.zeranoe.com/builds/`.
- `platform` is one of three options: `win64`, `win32` or `macos64`.
- `linking` is one of three options: `static`, `shared` or `dev`.
- `ffmpeg` is just "ffmpeg".
- `version` is the version (ex. `4.3` or `20200628-4cfcfb3`).
- Appending only `.zip` means that version of FFmpeg is under a GPL 3.0 license and appending `-lgpl.zip` means that version of FFmpeg is under an LGPL 3.0 license.

So assuming someone wished to download:

- The Windows 64-bit, shared library, LGPL 3.0 licensed version of FFmpeg 4.3
- The Windows 32-bit, statically-linked, GPL 3.0 licensed version of FFmpeg Git build 20200628-4cfcfb3

These URLs would look like:

*ex. Zeranoe FFmpeg URLs*

```
https://ffmpeg.zeranoe.com/builds/win64/shared/ffmpeg-4.3-win64-shared-lgpl.zip

https://ffmpeg.zeranoe.com/builds/win32/static/ffmpeg-20200628-4cfcfb3-win32-static.zip
```

---

*Note that it appears that the LGPL 3.0 license is only available with non-Git versions of FFmpeg distributed by Zeranoe. So ex. `ffmpeg-20200628-4cfcfb3-win32-static-lgpl.zip` would not be valid.*

---

**SHA256 Checksums**

The link to the appropriate SHA256 file for a given download is essentially the same URL construction with "sha256" inserted between the primary `url` and `platform` and ".sha256" tacked on to the end:

*ex. Zeranoe SHA256 URL Construction*

```
url/sha256/platform/linking/ffmpeg-version-platform-linking(.zip)(-lgpl.zip).sha256
```

The corresponding SHA256 URLs for the files above would look like:

*ex. Zeranoe FFmpeg SHA256 URLs*

```
https://ffmpeg.zeranoe.com/builds/sha256/win64/shared/ffmpeg-4.3-win64-shared-lgpl.zip.sha256

https://ffmpeg.zeranoe.com/builds/sha256/win32/static/ffmpeg-20200628-4cfcfb3-win32-static.zip.sha256
```

**Page Source Options**

FFmpeg version information is contained as plaintext in `<a>` (anchor) elements in the relevant HTML page sources from Zeranoe. You can use either the rendered version of `https://ffmpeg.zeranoe.com/builds/` or server-generated directory listings for a given build to provide these `<a>` elements, but there are some things to be aware of.

*Using ffmpeg.zeranoe.com/builds/*

Using `https://ffmpeg.zeranoe.com/builds/` to gather current version information has some downsides:

- `<a>` elements holding version information only contain version information:

  `<a role="menuitem" href="#" target="_self" class="dropdown-item">4.3</a>`

  This means you will need to construct the filename for your preferred download yourself.
- `<a>` elements for `https://ffmpeg.zeranoe.com/builds/` aren't all just versions numbers. Each `<a>` tag specifies a piece of flyout/drop-down text, meaning you will need to sort out version numbers manually in your script.
- `<a>` elements for `https://ffmpeg.zeranoe.com/builds/` are only rendered (via JavaScript) if the web page is visible in a browser window.

This last item means that normal command-line tools (ex. `curl`, `wget`, etc.) cannot be used to gather the page source from `https://ffmpeg.zeranoe.com/builds/` (though they can still be used for downloading files). As for browser automation (e.g. saving the page source with [Selenium WebDriver](https://www.selenium.dev/), rigging `Save As` with something like [AutoHotkey](https://www.autohotkey.com/), etc.), the browser window must be visible (i.e. you cannot use `headless` mode with Firefox/Chrome and Selenium).

*Using Server-Generated Directory Listings*

With the drawbacks listed above, parsing the HTML page source for `https://ffmpeg.zeranoe.com/builds/` may not be the preferable option. Currently, `https://ffmpeg.zeranoe.com/builds/` is simply a front-end to a number of openly available web directories with the forms:

*ex. Zeranoe FFmpeg Directories*

```
url/platform/linking
```

and

*ex. Zeranoe SHA256 Directories*

```
url/sha256/platform/linking
```

Where (again):

- `url` is `https://ffmpeg.zeranoe.com/builds/`.
- `platform` is one of three options: `win64`, `win32` or `macos64`.
- `linking` is one of three options: `static`, `shared` or `dev`.

So for *all* the e.g. Windows 32-bit statically-linked builds hosted by Zeranoe (and their corresponding SHA256 checksums), complete directory listings would be available at:

*ex. Zeranoe Windows 32-bit statically-linked builds*

```
https://ffmpeg.zeranoe.com/builds/win32/static/

https://ffmpeg.zeranoe.com/builds/sha256/win32/static/
```

Since these listings do not contain JavaScript (they return regular HTML), you can extract the necessary `<a>` elements without rendering them first in a browser:

```
<a href="ffmpeg-4.3-win32-dev.zip">ffmpeg-4.3-win32-dev.zip</a>
```

This means they won't be potentially missing and that the page source for each directory listing can be fetched with command line tools (ex. `curl`, `wget`, etc.).

---

*As a minor caveat, `curl -O` (`--remote-name`) will cause fetching the remote directory to fail. You need to manually specify a name for the output file (e.g. `curl -o zeranoe_win32.html https://ffmpeg.zeranoe.com/builds/win32/static/`).*

---

**Powershell Example**

Fetching `<a>` element text from a server-generated directory listing from Zeranoe in PowerShell:

*ex. extract_anchor_text.ps1*

```
# Print the text associated with each <a> element for the given Zeranoe
# server-generated directory listing at the command line.

$SiteAdress = "https://ffmpeg.zeranoe.com/builds/win32/static/"

$HttpContent = Invoke-WebRequest -URI $SiteAdress

# Get the href= value for each link
# $HttpContent.Links | Foreach {$_.href }

# Get the inner text between <a> and <\a> for each link
$HttpContent.Links | innerText
```

Note that in this instance, the text in the `href=` value is identical to the text between `<a>` and `<\a>` (as stated previously, no relevant `<a>` element contains a full download URL at this time):

*ex. extract_anchor_text.ps1 Output (Command Line)*

```
[...]
ffmpeg-20200626-7447045-win32-static.zip
ffmpeg-20200628-4cfcfb3-win32-static.zip
[...]
ffmpeg-4.3-win32-static-lgpl.zip
ffmpeg-4.3-win32-static.zip
```

If you would like to read a bit further on parsing HTML web pages with PowerShell, you can visit the link this example was taken from [here](http://woshub.com/parsing-html-webpages-with-powershell/).

Comment: You might want to check/fix broken links